# Stop execution until check is evaluated

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

How to stop execution until a condition evaluated, this code always return undefined:

```
function test() {
    var allGood;
    account.isUserAuthenticated().then(function(data) {
        if (data) {
            allGood = false;
        } else {
            allGood =  true;
        }
    });
    return allGood;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "stop execution"? This function always returns `undefined` because it does not wait for `isUserAuthenticated` to return (that's why the use of a promise, I think)

Comment: `function test() { return account.isUserAuthenticated().then(data => !data); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a result that is set inside of an asynchronous call (a promise) which means `allGood` is first returned (that's why it is `undefined`) and then sometime later it actually gets a value. What you should do instead is return the promise itself from your function:

```
function test() {
    return account.isUserAuthenticated().then(function(data) {
        if (data) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Then if you run:

```
test().then(function(allGood) {
  if (allGood) {
    // user is authenticated
  } else {
    // user is not authenticated
  }
});
```

Comment: Also you can use Promise.resolve() instead of return which is easy to understand to someone new in Promises, or at least was easiest for me.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: No, you cannot use `Promise.resolve` instead of `return`? I must have misunderstood you there.

Comment: @Bergi I have done a fiddle and I realize that Promise.resolve() needs to be returned. https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/uxdebvyL/1/